# Python Parsing Expression and replacing with another expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pyparsing

I am using `pyparsing`, and to parse some text, I created a grammar, and it works as expected, however, for a expression like this one:

```
OR(OR(in1, in2), in3)
```

I want to replace the nested expression, to an "alias" and then create an expression for this alias, in simple words:

```
# I have this expression ( OR(OR(in1, in2), in3) )
# Which I parsed to
parsed = ["OR", [["OR", ["in1", "in2"]], "in3"]]

# I want to have
exp1 = ["OR", ["in1", "in2"]]
exp2 = ["OR", ["exp1", "in3"]]
```

This is a minimal example, however I can have any nested "expressions" (with only two arguments). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a parser that is probably similar to the one you wrote:

```
import pyparsing as pp

LPAR, RPAR = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
OR = pp.Keyword("OR")
term = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier

or_expr = pp.Forward()
or_expr <<= pp.Group(OR + pp.Group(LPAR + pp.delimitedList(or_expr | term)) + RPAR)
```

When it parses the string you gave, it provides the same nested output.

To create the "expN" expression names, you can use a parse action to gather up the expressions, and associated expression id, in a global list var:

```
# add parse action to convert OR's to exprs
exprs = []
def generate_expr_definition(tokens):
    expr_name = "exp{}".format(len(exprs)+1)
    exprs.append((expr_name, tokens.asList()[0]))
    return expr_name
or_expr.addParseAction(generate_expr_definition)
```

When you run this parser, the created results aren't the important part. What is important is the `exprs` list that was built while parsing:

```
or_expr.parseString(sample)

# generate assignments for each nested OR expr
for name, expr in exprs:
    print("{} = {}".format(name, expr))
```

This gives:

```
exp1 = ['OR', ['in1', 'in2']]
exp2 = ['OR', ['exp1', 'in3']]
```

Now I look at that, and ask, "how will I know the difference between `'exp1'` that was parsed from the input vs. `'exp1'` that is supposed to represent a parsed expression. If this is to be interpreted as a Python assignment, it should really read:

```
exp2 = ['OR', [exp1, 'in3']]
```

with no quotes around the variable name.

To do this, we need to return an object from the parse action that will `repr` as the name without the surrounding quotes. Like this:

```
class ExprName:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self._name
```

Change the return statement in the parse action to:

```
return ExprName(expr_name)
```

And the resulting output now looks like:

```
exp1 = ['OR', ['in1', 'in2']]
exp2 = ['OR', [exp1, 'in3']]
```

Now you can distinguish the generated `expN` vars from parsed inputs.

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm, didn't know that pyparsing was so powerful, I was thinking on traversing the parse tree to get the expressions, and this actually does what I wanted in the first place, that was getting ordered expression from bottom to root

Comment: I have one more question, what happens when I dont have a nested expression? because I dont want to replace names when I have a simple expression such as OR(in1,in2)

Comment: Does this happen? I don't think my test does that (look at the posted output in my answer).